# Is there any other way to make table responsive which is created by using datatables Jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, datatables, footable

I want to make my table responsive for mobile and web .i am using datatables jquery 1.8 plugin for  my tables.i have seen the [Foo table script](http://themergency.com/footable/) make that responsive by using hide/show machnisam .is there any option to make table responsive without hiding the columns ?

Comment: Explain more on what you mean by responsive.

Comment: i mean that table will fit to wide range of screens.like for laptop screens , mobile and tablets screens as foo table do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the solution for my problem take a look on this [datatables-responsive](https://github.com/Comanche/datatables-responsive)

Comment: This link really helps. I was also the problem much similar to yours

Answer (score 0):

I dint get what you said, If i am not wrong then you want your table to be responsive on all screens. Why dont you follow this [link](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) 
I have been using this way to get responsive tables. This is done with pure css3 features. Take a look on that link.

Comment: yes i want my table to be responsive on all screens but i am using datatables jquery plugin to create HTML table dynamically from server side.i have only table tag of html and on the bases of that tag datatables plugin create full table(i.e. thead and tbody) .your reference link make table responsive if we have table header on and table body on html(on clint side).